How to make an index with PCA?
I'm new to PCA and have a question about interpreting the results. In R, I can obtain the component loadings and scores. To create an index, should I just add these scores together? Are the scores already projected into the new space? Additionally, if we want to use three components, should we add the scores directly, or do we need to weight them?

Lots of similar questions on this topic: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=index+pca+answers%3A1
